# How can I make UITableView less sensitive to vertical scrolling?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have table view that has more than 10 rows and inside each row I'm placing a hortizontally-scrolling scrollview (you can thumb through images much like in Coverflow).

The problem is that UITableView is too sensitive to vertical scrolling. When I'm trying to scroll left and right in a particular scrollview (inside of any cell), the table view starts scrolling up or down once it detects even the slightest movement of my finger upon the y-axis.

Is there a way I can change this and set a higher vertical-scroll threshold for the table view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple suggestions. Try them and see how they feel.

**Suggestion 1**

When you dequeue your tableViewCells, try calling this:

`[tableView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:cell.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];`

**Suggestion 2**

Try setting this on your tableView:

`self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`

That property defaults to `YES`. It delays touches to the content of the table view cells by a fraction of a second, to help it recognize the difference between a tap and a drag.

Comment: The first suggestion is very clever idea but it's not really helping much. Same goes for the second suggestion (which, to be honest, in conjunction with the first suggestion I thought might work). Thanks for your answer though - again, clever idea on Suggestion 1.

Comment: I just realized that the first suggestion couldn't actually work because that's only going to require the pan gesture to fail on the last cell that the table view asks to draw which in my case is cell number 3. Cell number 3, off the start, is actually a bit better with scrolling than the other two. I would have the table view require pan gestures to fail on ALL the cell scrollviews. I don't suppose there's a way to set that?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, requiring gesture recognizers to fail can be called multiple times. It's a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I am right. Apple even has some sample code in the Collection View programming guide that makes use of this technique. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH4-SW4

Comment: So, it will track all of the cells gesture's and require that only one fails and it will not scroll?

Comment: Read the UIGestureRecognizer docs for a more detailed explanation, but essentially each gesture recognizer goes through a series of recognition states (began/possble/recognized/etc.) as it tracks touches. Requiring another gesture recognizer to fail means that your recognizer won't progress all the way to "recognized" until all the other recognizers you have required to fail are in an idle or failed state.

Comment: As long as one or more of those other recognizers are in began/possible states, your recognizer will not proceed to "recognized".

Comment: Hi Jared, i am trying to create a feed page like facebook using tableview. The tableview stops scrolling on random cells after regular  usage of the app. The weird thing is the scroll works for the same cell if you apply two fingers to scroll.Please help